# Sublime Regex Search and Increment

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, sublimetext3

I would like to know if its possible, to select all the numerics inside each square brackets i.e;

```
myarray[1]
```

I would like to select all numerics inside all arrays in a page (Sublime); and then increment them using insertNums or something else. - The incrementation need to increment after each 2. so 0 0, 1 1, 2 2, etc should be the outcome.

If anyone is kind enough to help, thanks. :)

Comment: please give a sample input

Comment: I have a page of php, with a lot of arrays in it;

`array1[0]
array1[0]
array1[0]
array1[0]`

And the output should be

`array1[0]
array1[0]
array1[1]
array1[1]`

Using regex and sublime (including insertnums plugin)

Comment: what is the difference between the input and the output, i am not very sure sir

Comment: The arrays (numbers), 0 0, 1 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you are looking for this :

```
(\d+)(?=[^\[]*(?=\]|$))
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/kU4lY1/2

Comment: That works fine thanks, do you know of a way to increment via sublime? I know how to increment in 1's, but I want to get 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 etc.. not 1 2 3 4 5 6.. Thanks..